# Chrome know about all apps installed on my pc

Tags: google-chrome, privacy

There is a feature in chrome to check for malware in your pc. If I once used it, it does not find any malware, does it store and connect to my email what apps I had? More concerning, does it know configurations of those apps too?

Comment: Even if the answer is "no" today, it could be "yes" tomorrow. Don't install software if you don't trust it

Comment: "There is a feature in Chrome to check for malware in your PC." - Sounds like you have an extension installed because what you describe is NOT a feature of the current version of Chrome.

Comment: @Ramhound I vaguely recall that Chrome actually prompts you to run a malware scan under some conditions. The internet seems to confirm this: https://duo.com/decipher/heres-why-chrome-is-scanning-your-computer-for-malware